# How can i print Multiple Object from firebase realtime database?

Tags: javascript, php, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am printing multiple Objects from `firebase` database but i am getting null value I am new to `firebase`

I am getting null in result and i want `Shubham manojm mohit` in  output

[image]

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child("messages");

        rootRef.on("child_added", snap =>{
             var name = snap.child("name").val();
              $("#users").append('<div class="row sideBar-body"><div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3 sideBar-avatar"><div class="avatar-icon"><img src="http://chat.synetal.com/assets/user2.jpg"></div></div><div class="col-sm-9 col-xs-9 sideBar-main"><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-8 sideBar-name" id="chat"><span class="name-meta">'+ name +'</span></div><div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4 pull-right sideBar-time"><span class="time-meta pull-right">18:18</span></div></div></div></div>'); 
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use :   .on("value")
and then use "key" instead of "name"

```
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child("messages");



rootRef.once('value', function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
var name = childSnapshot.key;
var childData = childSnapshot.val();
console.log(name, childData);
$("#users").append('<div class="row sideBar-body"><div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3 sideBar-avatar"><div class="avatar-icon"><img src="http://chat.synetal.com/assets/user2.jpg"></div></div><div class="col-sm-9 col-xs-9 sideBar-main"><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-8 sideBar-name" id="chat"><span class="name-meta">'+ name +'</span></div><div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4 pull-right sideBar-time"><span class="time-meta pull-right">18:18</span></div></div></div></div>'); 
});
});
```

Comment: Hey its not working, i tried your code but its not giving any output

Comment: Try the consoloe.log in the edit to see what is up in the datasnapshot

Comment: jQuery.Deferred exception: rootref is not defined ReferenceError: rootref is not defined

Comment: jquery-3.4.0.min.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: rootref is not defined

Comment: console.log prints nothing

Comment: its working thank you so much but there is one problem when database has new object like Ankit then on frontend it gives  Shubham

manojm

mohit

Ankit

Shubham

manojm

mohit

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.